# Apps compiled with Py2app won't run on other Macs

Tags: python, macos, py2app

So I've written a code and wanted to make it a standalone. I used py2app and successfully created the app. The app runs on my computer perfectly, however when I try to run it on other Macs, an error comes out...

**Error is:**

> You can't open the application "Auto Wallpaper" because it is not supported on this type of Mac.

My code has got a GUI (written with TKinter) and it is compiled with python 3.9  (maybe this is the problem).
I tried to use other py2app versions (I tried py2app 0.16-0.21 other ones wouldn't start on my computer too), but every version gave me an error.
Both of the Macs (iMac 21.5 Late 2009 and MBA Mid 2011) has High Sierra.

The **setup.py** code is here (if it helps you anyways):

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Auto_Specified_Wallpapers.py']
DATA_FILES = ["SaveFile.txt"]
OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile':'AutoW.icns',
    'includes': ['requests', 'bs4', 'pyautogui'],
    'excludes': ['numpy', 'Image'],
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': "Auto Wallpaper",
        'CFBundleDisplayName': "Auto Wallpaper",
        'CFBundleGetInfoString': "Download Wallpapers",
        'CFBundleIdentifier': "com.metachris.osx.sandwich",
        'CFBundleVersion': "0.2.3",
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': "0.2.3",
    }
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    name= "Auto Wallpaper",
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

I hope someone can help me out with this. How can I make it run on "every" Mac?

Comment: What command did you use when you compiled the app in the terminal? Was it in alias mode?

Comment: I used every other combination of py2app (I used 0.22) and changed my setup file a bit, and unexpectedly it started working?  I actually don't know what made it run. But thanks for your comment @SamanthaCruz !

Comment: @BarisSayit can you share the changes?